# python selenium click on multiple survey buttons error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://wj.qq.com/s/2214142/51db') # survey link

# First page - click "Next" button, it works
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('survey_nextpage') # it works
button.click()


# Second page - click one of the scale button between 1-5 
# it always clicks the first button found. how to set to randomly 
# choose from one of the five buttons?

answer = browser.find_element_by_class_name('star_item') 
answer.click()
```

I am new to selenium and testing my code on a survey website link.

The first page - It successfully clicks the "Next" button .

The second page - It contains first button which indicates a 1-5 scale. 
My code always clicks the first button it found. My goal is to randomly pick a button between 1-5 scale and click it. I tried to write a loop but it does not work.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is javascirpt a tag for this?

Comment: @SheshankS. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all elements have the same class name, you can use the plural `elements` to use the function that returns a list of the elements instead of just the first one:

```
answers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('star_item') 
answers[2].click()
```

Comment: `ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)`  I just tried this method, it gives error like this. It this a Chrome problem? @nosklo

Comment: I tried it on Edge. It works.  I don't know why it does not work with Chrome.

Comment: @QianLi that is a different problem, maybe ask another question?

Comment: I will. Thanks a lot for the help! @nosklo

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@class, 'star_item')]") 

option = random.choice(options)
option.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated! @NewBee

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have 5 buttons with tag `<button>`. Then you can locate this buttons like this:

```
answers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath') # gives a list with 5 elements (buttons)
```

PS if you provide HTML block with all 5 buttons I can find a `xPath` to them. Then you want to peak randomly one of this buttons. You can do like this:

```
import random

list = [20, 16, 10, 5];
random.shuffle(list)
print ("Reshuffled list : ",  list)

random.shuffle(list)
print ("Reshuffled list : ",  list)
```

Output:

```
Reshuffled list :  [16, 5, 10, 20]
reshuffled list :  [20, 5, 10, 16]
```

In your case it would be like this:

```
import random

answers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
random_list = list(range(len(answers))) # creates a list with ascending numbers 0 ... len(answers)
random.shuffle(random_list)
answers[random_list[0]].click() # click randomly on one of the buttons
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and detailed explanation! @Andrei Suvorkov